# awk find the second record between two strings / awk search in file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I'm trying to use awk to find content in the same script that awk is.

my file looks like this :

```
    function fanv {
            bla bla
      }

echo "something"
awk '/start/,/end/ {c=2}c&&c--'  test.sh >> outputfile

exit 0

#start
string that needs to be print 
#end
```

The problem is that awk gets as input all the file (can't rely on line numbers) , hence the result is also the text of the awk expression.
Furthermore, operation `{c=2}c&&c--` is not working , I'm probably missing something.

The result of the outfile is :

```
awk '/start/,/end/ {c=2}c&&c--'  test.sh >> outputfile
#start
string that need to be print 
#end
```

How can I select the second record from awk , so that the output file will contain only

> string that need to be print

Comment: Could you please add sample Input_file and ecpected output file too in you post with code tags, so that we could clearly understand the question.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 the input and expected output are already in the question, the file is the script itself and the output it `string that needs to be print`

Comment: I apologies Eric, but I really didn't understand as expected output and sample Input_file was not clear to me(I am not that intelligent :)), so only I asked OP to add it into post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk 'p && /^#end/{ p=0; print lines }
     p{ lines=(lines==""?$0:lines ORS $0) }
     /^#start/{ p=1; lines="" }' file

string that need to be print
```

There are 3 condition and actions blocks:

- `p && /^#end/{ p=0; print lines }` - when `p==1` and we got a line starting with `#end`. We reset flag `p` and print our buffer.
- `p{ lines=(lines==""?$0:lines ORS $0) }` - when `p==1` we keep appending all lines into a buffer
- `/^#start/{ p=1; lines="" }` - When we got a line starting with `#start`, we set flag `p` and reset `lines` buffer.

Comment: working perfect Thanks. i don't know the syntax but i'll thanks

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use a simple character class containing only one character.  That way the pattern will match the text you search, but the pattern itself won't be matched.  My approach is usually to set a flag about whether to print lines or not, so I'd do something like:

```
awk '/[e]nd/ {do_it=0} do_it {print} /[s]tart/ {do_it=1}' test.sh >> outputfile
```

Comment: It will print lines even if there is no `end` tag

Comment: @anubhava good point, I don't know what the OP would want to have happen there, but it could make things answer wrong

Comment: yes @anubhava that is right. it's mix son function that continues the end

Comment: @yntnm so if there is no string `end` in the script you want `awk` to print nothing at all?

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/start$/,/end$/ { if ( $0 !~ /start$/ && $0 !~ /end$/ ) print $0 }' test.sh >> outputfile
```

Check for lines ending with the text "end" and "start" and process these lines, Then check to ensure that none of the lines within pattern match against end or start. If they don't print the lines.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is:

```
awk '/^#end/{f=0} f; /^#start/{f=1}' file
```